# Workaround to seeing data factory v2 debug runs

Tags: azure-data-factory

I realise normally a debug run is not visible in the data factory v2 UI after closing the browser window, however unfortunately I needed to restart my machine unexpectedly and it's a long running pipeline.

I thought maybe the runs might be available via powershell, but I haven't had any luck.

The pipeline is likely still running.

We do have external logging, however ideally I'd like to see how long each activity is taking as I'm load testing.

And more importantly I do not want to do another run until I'm sure it's finished.... notably I'll run it from a trigger next time (just in case!).

---

EDIT:
It looks like a sandbox id is used which is stored in the browser local storage and there appears to be undocumented API endpoints for gathering info using the sandbox id. But there doesn't appear to be a way of getting old sandbox id's so I'm probably out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a button for view all debug runs. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that button is only active for that session as far as I can tell, if you close the window and reopen I don't think you'll see them.

Comment: It is always there. Just hover on that icon.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is, I believe if you close the browser and reopen it I don't see previous debug runs. Do you?

Comment: if it is still running, you should be able to see it. For example, just debug a wait activity for 5 minutes. That api is query ADF backend service, not browser cache. If you hit F12, you should be able to find the network trace in network tab of browser debug tool.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out some more when I get a sec. Last time I tried it appeared as though the browser was storing the debug session ids, but I suspect perhaps now it was that the run has finished or errored in the background.

Comment: you can see a list of active runs but cannot get to any details of where the run is up to

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/iterative-development-debugging#monitoring-debug-runs):

> To view a historical view of debug runs or see a list of all active debug runs, you can go into the Monitor experience.
>
> [image]